# Highcharts - Small column not clickable when covered with a (sp)line serie

Tags: highcharts

We are using Highcharts to display data in **column** series combined with some **spline** series. All columns are clickable (to perform a drilldown) but some columns become unclickable because they are somewhat small and are entirely covered by the mouse tracking layer of the spline series.

It can be  solved partially by disabling the mouse tracking in the spline series, but then the tooltip is not available for that series, and we need that.

What we need is that the column should be **clickable through the mouse tracking layer** of the spline series.

I've put an example on [JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx0pgk3x/4/) to demonstrate the issue.

```
events: {
    click: function () 
       {
           alert('I\'m Jane');
       }
}
```

In this example, all 'Jane' columns are clickable, except for the second one (oranges) because it's too small and get's covered by the invisible mouseTracking layer of the spline series

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentionned, you need to disable the moustracking event for the spline series.
To retrieve all series in the tooltip you can use the following code:

```
tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '';
            s += '<table style="border-style: hidden;border-collapse: collapse;">';

            //get the chart object
            var chart = this.points[0].series.chart;

            //get the categories array
            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories; 
            var index = 0;

            //compute the index of corr y value in each data arrays  
            while (this.x !== categories[index]) { index++; }

            //loop through series array
            $.each(chart.series, function (i, series) { 

                s += '<tr><td style="color:' + series.color + '">' + series.name + ':</td>';
                s += '<td style="text-align:right;color:' + series.color + '">';
                s += series.data[index].y.toFixed();
                s += '</td></tr>';
            });

            s += "</table>";
            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    }
```